# How to take only last five option in datalist and clear all other option in a datalist using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, empty-list

I want to empty my datalist but I do not want to clear last five option is there any way to do this?

Here is my code -

```
$('#results').empty().append(options);
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

To remove all but the last 5 elements in a jQuery object you can use `slice()` with a negative index, like this:

```js
$('datalist option').slice(0, -5).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Lorem"> <!-- will be removed -->
    <option value="Ipsum"> <!-- will be removed -->
    <option value="Dolor"> <!-- will be removed -->
    <option value="Sit"> <!-- will be removed -->
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>
```